# undefined method `information_clients_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000014f00>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to display the pages I scaffolded with my terminal. It is to create additional information when a user signed up

This is my error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `information_clients_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x00000000014f00>):
    1: <%= form_with(model: information_client) do |form| %>
    2:   <% if information_client.errors.any? %>
    3:     <div style="color: red">
    4:       <h2><%= pluralize( information_client.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this information_client from being saved:</h2>

app/views/information_client/_form.html.erb:1
app/views/information_client/new.html.erb:3
```

This is my information_*client*_controller.rb

```
# GET /information_clients or /information_clients.json
   def index
     @information_clients = InformationClient.all
  end

   # GET /information_clients/1 or /information_clients/1.json
    def show
    end

  # GET /information_clients/new
   def new
     @information_client = InformationClient.new
  end

  # GET /information_clients/1/edit
   def edit
   end

   # POST /information_clients or /information_clients.json
   def create
     @information_client = InformationClient.new(information_client_params)
   end


   def information_client_params
    params.permit(:image)
  end
```

This is my `routes.rb`

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :information_client
end
```

And my rails routes on terminal:

```
   Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                                       Controller#Action
                information_client_index GET    /information_client(.:format)                                                                     information_client#index
                                         POST   /information_client(.:format)                                                                     information_client#create
                  new_information_client GET    /information_client/new(.:format)                                                                 information_client#new
                 edit_information_client GET    /information_client/:id/edit(.:format)                                                            information_client#edit
                      information_client GET    /information_client/:id(.:format)                                                                 information_client#show
                                         PATCH  /information_client/:id(.:format)                                                                 information_client#update
                                         PUT    /information_client/:id(.:format)                                                                 information_client#update
                                         DELETE /information_client/:id(.:format)                                                                 information_client#destroy
```

I know this path is for

```
<%= link_to "Back to information clients", information_clients_path %>
```

I tried removing it, but the error still appears

Comment: the routes file should have `resources :information_clients` or if you want a singular resource, it should be `resource :information_client`

Comment: @Matt the reason is that resource name is singular, not plural

Answer (score 1):

You are displaying a form to create a new information_client and, [based on the convention](https://rubyonrails.org/doctrine#convention-over-configuration), Rails is trying to submit this form to the '/information_clients' path. In order fill the action in the form tag correctly it's using the URL Helper `information_clients_path`, again based on the convention.

In the `routes.rb` you don't have the '/information_clients'. What you have instead is the '/information_client'. That is because the resource you have in the `routes.rb` is in **singular**. To follow the convention, resources should be in plural: `resources :information_clients`

Answer (score 0):

Change `information_clients_path` to `information_client_index_path` as in your `rails routes` output:

```
<%= link_to "Back to information clients", information_client_index_path %>
```

```
<%= form_with(model: information_client, url: information_client_index_path) do |form| %>
```

First one is for GET request, second one for POST request in the form action

---

Or another option: rename resource name

In this case you need:

- use plural resources name `resources :information_clients` (s in the end)
- rename `app/views/information_client` folder to `app/views/information_clients`
- rename `information_client_controller.rb` file to `information_clients_controller.rb`
- rename `InformationClientController` class to `InformationClientsController`

In that case your link should work. And form action URL too. Because of following of standard names convention

---

Second option is more preferred by convention. But it is up to you to choose by your needs